# PowerShell Internet Explorer Com Object Select Class Drop Down Menu Item

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I am trying to select an item from a drop down menu in the HTML below.

```html
<select class="select" name="expiration">
<option value="N" selected="selected">Never</option>
<option value="10M">10 Minutes</option>
<option value="1H">1 Hour</option>
<option value="1D">1 Day</option>
<option value="1W">1 Week</option>
<option value="2W">2 Weeks</option>
<option value="1M">1 Month</option>
```

Here is my current code. I don't receive any errors, just the item doesn't get selected.

```
# Code to select menu item
$ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible = $False

# navigate to URL
$ie.navigate('http://URL')
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; }

$expiration = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('expiration')
$expiration.outerText |Select-Object -Index 2
$ie.Document.getElementById('submit').Click()
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$result = $ie.LocationURL
```

Comment: did you try -  $expiration.Options.SelectedIndex = 2  ?

Comment: Yes, The property 'SelectedIndex' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: `$expiration = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName('expiration')` what is the value of `$expiration` after this line ? The `class` on your `select` element is `select` not `expiration`. Moreover I don't think you can select an element in a list on a webpage with PO's `Select`, it will only filter what you pipe to it but not act on the webpage

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.Visible = $False
$ie.navigate("http://URL")
while ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000 }

$expiration = $ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("select")
$expiration.Options.SelectedIndex = 2
$ie.Document.getElementById("submit").Click()
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
$result = $ie.LocationURL
```